# gradle: run twice InstallDist task with different jar configuration

Tags: java, gradle

For packaging reasons, I need as part of my build, to run twice `installDist` task, in order to generate two distributions. In each of them, the main jar will contain different ressource folders.

**Example**

Let's assume I want to generate:

- first a distribution in which main jar excludes both files `f1` and `f2`
- then a distribution in which main jar excludes file `f1` only

I tried the following without success:

```
tasks = ['installDist', ...., 'osXjar', 'installDist', ... ]

    jar {
           archiveName = xxx
           exclude "f1"
           exclude "f2"
        }


task osXjar(type: Jar) {
           archiveName = xxx
           exclude "f1"
        }
```

It generate twice the same result, I think that `installDist` only depends on jar and ignores osXjar

Also if try to run only the custom jar task `osXjar`, the generated jar is broken and has a ridicoulsly small size, whereas the jar task is producing correct result.

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

So I post the answer here in case someone ran into the same issue. 
The trick is to include `from sourceSets.main.output` within custom jar task. 
Hence, the following would work:

```
tasks = ['installDist', ...., 'osXjar', 'installDist', ... ]

    jar {
           archiveName = xxx
           exclude "f1"
           exclude "f2"
        }


task osXjar(type: Jar) {
           archiveName = xxx
           from sourceSets.main.output
           exclude "f1"
        }
```